# virtualenv directory shifted to the end of $PATH when running zsh -l -c 'echo "__${PATH}__"'

Tags: python, macos, shell, virtualenv, zsh

Why is the virtualenv path shifted to the end in the last command?

```
Last login: Tue Aug 26 19:14:49 on ttys000
➜  ~  echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin
➜  ~  zsh -l -c 'echo "__${PATH}__"'
__/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin__
➜  ~  . ./venvs/py_venv/bin/activate
(py_venv)➜  ~  echo $PATH
/Users/aj/venvs/py_venv/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin
(py_venv)➜  ~  zsh -l -c 'echo "__${PATH}__"'
__/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/aj/venvs/py_venv/bin__
(py_venv)➜  ~
```

**EDIT:**

Further investigation seems to indicate it is has to do with single quotes vs double quotes. Still not sure why:

```
(py_venv)➜  ~  zsh -l -c "echo $PATH"
/Users/aj/venvs/py_venv/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin
(py_venv)➜  ~  zsh -l -c 'echo $PATH'
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/aj/venvs/py_venv/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

In my (*Ubuntu*) *zsh* environment I don't see a behavioral difference, but I suspect in your case (perhaps related to something specific to *OS X*) it may have something to do with the fact that *double quotes* allow for full substitution, whereas *single quotes* do not.

For example, if you run `echo '$PATH'`, it will literally output `$PATH`, whereas `echo "$PATH"` will substitute the value of the environment variable into the echo command and output the full path.

[Further reading on zsh quoting](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide05.html)

**Edit:**

I tried a few variations of your exact zsh command, and can reproduce something similar, although I end up with no output instead of it shifting to the end:

```
 (venv_test) ~  zsh -l -c 'echo "__$PATH__"'
__
 (venv_test) ~  zsh -l -c 'echo __$PATH__' 
__
 (venv_test) ~  zsh -l -c "echo __$PATH__"
__
 (venv_test) ~  zsh -l -c "echo __${PATH}__"
__/home/khampson/virtualenvs/venv_test/bin:/home/khampson/bin__
```

Try switching to *double quotes* with *curly braces* around the env var (I suspect otherwise the trailing underscores are being treated as part of the env var name).

Comment: This was part of the issue. ```zsh -l -c "echo $PATH"``` was doing full substitution so the undesired string ```echo /Users/aj/venvs/py_venv/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin``` was being passed to -c. Whereas with ```zsh -l -c 'echo $PATH'``` the desired string ```echo $PATH``` was being passed to -c. The reason the venv directory is shifted to the end is because of an annoying Mac OS X quirk which I'll add an answer for below.

Answer (score 0):

From the zsh man page:

```
STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES
       Commands are first read from /etc/zshenv; this cannot be overridden....
```

So let's see what Mac OS X has in there by default:

```
➜  ~  cat /etc/zshenv
# system-wide environment settings for zsh(1)
if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
    eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi
```

Ok, what is `/usr/libexec/path_helper`?

```
➜  ~  man path_helper
DESCRIPTION
     The path_helper utility reads the contents of the files in the directories /etc/paths.d and /etc/manpaths.d and appends their contents to the PATH and MANPATH environment variables respectively.
```

So if path_helper ***appends***, then why is the venv directory being pushed to the end? The answer is it doesn't append, it prepends and the docs are incorrect. It also seems to be doing some deduping:

```
(py_venv)➜  ~  echo $PATH
/Users/aj/venvs/py_venv/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin
(py_venv)➜  ~  /usr/libexec/path_helper -s
PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/aj/venvs/py_venv/bin"; export PATH;
(py_venv)➜  ~  PATH="" /usr/libexec/path_helper -s
PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin"; export PATH;
(py_venv)➜  ~  PATH="/foo/bar" /usr/libexec/path_helper -s
PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/foo/bar"; export PATH;
(py_venv)➜  ~  PATH="/foo/bar:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin" /usr/libexec/path_helper -s
PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/foo/bar"; export PATH;
(py_venv)➜  ~
```